# How to build a house on a giant rhino?

Tags: engineering

In my world, Rhino's have mutated and evolved to become larger than elephants. If I wanted to put some sort of dwelling on one (assume its trained) how would I go about doing that?

EDIT:

The dwelling is for humans, it needs to be livable but not luxurious, its sole purpose is survival.

Comment: Rhinos of all animals. I see two big issues. Firstly [rhino's are notoriously bad tempered](https://youtu.be/xL6CUdw84jI) and secondarily you will run into the usual issues with the [square cube law](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SquareCubeLaw) as you attempt to scale up existing creatures.

Comment: Dwelling for whom? The requirements for a dwelling for humans is different than a dwelling for sentient gnats.

Comment: First, train your rhino not to roll :-)

Comment: This does not seem hygienic, when you think of the plumbing.

Answer (score 4):

> In my world, Rhino's have mutated and evolved to become larger than elephants.

Look at what is available for elephants, then. First thing that comes to mind is a [howdah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howdah)

> A howdah, or houdah (Hindi: हौदा haudā, Bengali: হাওদা haoda), derived from the Arabic هودج (hawdaj), that means "bed carried by a camel", also known as hathi howdah (हाथी हौदा), is a carriage which is positioned on the back of an elephant, or occasionally some other animal such as a camel, used most often in the past to carry wealthy people or for use in hunting or warfare.

[image: howdah]

As a house is rather basic, a bit fancier and not larger than a capsule hotel room, probably. But it gives you shelter from the elements (provided you have something on the walls) and a surface to sleep and to reside. Forget about parties, though.